# Gas Pedal, Power breaks/Steering stops working... for a while?

Tags: toyota, starting, stall, celica

I was just driving my car in a parking lot.  After driving for about 15-20 minutes my gas pedal stops working! This has happened once before, I wasn't *too* surprised. I waited for about 3 minutes and started it up again. The pedal worked for about 10 seconds. Then it died again. Luckily I was able to get into a spot, and I walked to the mall. An hour later, it started fine and I drove it home. Last time this happened, I waited 10 minutes and started it, and it was fine.

Also: Power steering and power brakes stopped working at the same time as the pedal did. Also, the idling speed of the engine still worked and I could slowly inch into a safe spot. Very strange.

Another thing that is possible related: if I idle too long, the engine will die. The lights will stay on of course, but the engine just... turns off. If you try to start it, it doesn't start - instead it makes that noise right before the engine starts (sorry, I don't know the term! You know, that healthy "che-che-che-che" right before the "vroooom"? It doesn't sound like a dead battery, just a constant checheche). After trying to start it for like 5 minutes, sometimes it starts... but every time I've managed this (twice) the gas pedal phenomenon occurs merely minutes later. If I wait 10-20 minutes, it'll always start up, and I'll be fine! Sometimes the car isn't in idle when this happens, but after leaving my car idling for like 10 minutes as a test, it does, so I know idling can cause it.

***Summary:***

**Car**: 90 Celica

**Recently replaced parts:** fuel pump, distributor, ignition, regulator

**Stuff that seems to cause it:** Longer drives (30 minutes)

**Stuff that happens:** No gas pedal, no power breaks and steering, and won't start for a while after stopping car. Engine still runs and goes that default idling speed thing

**Other problems:** When idling a long time, engine can die, which makes this problem likely to occur if I can get engine to start after 5 minutes. Wait 15-20 and it'll be fine.

*The car hasn't started around 4 times in the past week or so, (and worked after 10-20 minutes) and the gas has died while driving twice, as well as the engine dying while idle once in a test I did at home.*

Thanks so much! :D

Comment: how low does the engine idle go when you lose power brakes a steering? have you tried putting a fuel pressure gauge on the car when it no starts? it makes me think theres an electrical or fuel delivery problem. if you have a multimeter do a sweep test on the throttle position sensor as well.